# How to use Log4Net in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin.ios, log4net

I have a app using Xamarin MonoTouch and i want to use logging framework in it. Searching i came across Log4Net (http://logging.apache.org/log4net/) library popularly used on .Net platform. I couldn't find a way to integrate it in my app. 
Once i download the dll from Apache, is there any setting i have to do in my app? What i have to code with any exception or console.writeline message to get that in log?

Is there any other logging framework that can be used with Xamarin?

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: did anybody found a solution !! I am also trying this

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Xamarin/MT friendly fork of Log4Net:

https://github.com/drunkirishcoder/monotouch-log4net

Comment: Thanks Jason. It is not very clear of what exactly i have to do, which files i need to include in the project. Do i just need to create a plain xml configuration file with all the appenders mentioned there? Even Example doesn't really give an idea?